# Removing incomplete data from being displayed on the web

Tags: reactjs

Say I am calling a dataset from an API and one of the objects in the data set is missing one element and I want to avoid any displaying the object with missing data. Also, I want to sort the data when it gets displayed by name (ascending).

Object example:

```
{
  "id": "a75e7343-23f3-45c4-a1a4-e88746b11ebf",
  "name": "Oakridge",
  "imgUrl": "",
  "group": "South West"
}
```

I would like to delete `Oakridge` from being displayed as the image url is not available.

For sorting I used the following way, but it did not work:

```
axios.get(`https://a18fda49-215e-47d1-9dc6-c6136a04a33a.mock.pstmn.io/communities?sort=name`);
```

My website for reference: https://flamboyant-ptolemy-e16fec.netlify.com/

Comment: For the sorting part, it looks like that will be done in the backend (because of the URL parameter you are sending). But you need to make sure the backend has that capability of sorting using that specific parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array with only the items that have `imgUrl`:

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: "a75e7343-23f3-45c4-a1a4-e88746b11ebf",
    name: "Oakridge",
    imgUrl: "",
    group: "South West"
  },
  {
    id: "a75e7343-23f3-45c4-a1a4-e88746b11ebg",
    name: "Oakridge 2",
    imgUrl: "http://image.com",
    group: "South West"
  }
];

const itemsWithImage = items.filter((item) => item.imgUrl);

console.log(itemsWithImage);
```

We are basically just filtering out items with [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (which include empty string) for `imgUrl`. If you want to remove an empty space as well, for example, you need to change the `filter`'s callback (e.g., `(item) => item.imgUrl && item.imgUrl.trim()`).

Comment: sorry I am new to this, but I tried to add what you said and it was giving me an error, I want to add the filter to the following                                                                   const resp = await axios.get(`https://a18fda49-215e-47d1-9dc6-c6136a04a33a.mock.pstmn.io/communities`);
    this.setState({community: resp.data, loading: false});

Comment: @alhaifi what's the error? You can do this: `this.setState({community: resp.data.filter((item) => item.imgUrl), loading: false});`. Or, for a more readable code, you can create a variable first for the filtered data, and then assign it to the `community` property.

Comment: Man you are the best, Thank you very much. It worked.  What I want to generalize it.  if anyfield of that data is empty, do not display it.  another thing, I tried to sort by axios.get(`https://a18fda49-215e-47d1-9dc6-c6136a04a33a.mock.pstmn.io/communities?sort=name` and it is not sorting

Comment: @alhaifi To have a generic filtering, you can use `Object.values` and `every`, having something like this in the `filter`'s callback: `(item) => Object.values(item).every(Boolean)`. Regarding sorting, you would have to check if the backend really supports this parameter.

Comment: @alhaifi If my main answer helps you, please mark it as accepted :). And feel free to shoot any other related questions.